# Tomcat : org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanResourcePaths No TLD files were found in resource path [/WEB-INF/ ]

Tags: tomcat

With Tomcat 8.5, I've excluded many jars (subject to log message) with `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip`

Even if most jars excluded are under `WEB-INF/lib` I still get this last message :

`11:17:58.161 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanResourcePaths No TLD files were found in resource path [/WEB-INF/].`

So how can I get rid of it ? I suspect a non-deployment because of it.
I tried to add /WEB-INF (or near) to the list of `jarsToSkip` but the message remains.

Thank you.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/1096291/ignore-directory-in-tomcat-tldscanner

Comment: Thank you, so I understand that there's no solution ...

Comment: well, it's just a log output - you can configure the logging to omit this level of detail

Answer (score 0):

This message is not important, see 8.5.79 TldScanner source :

```
 /**
 * Scan web application resources for TLDs, recursively.
 *
 * @param startPath the directory resource to scan
 * @throws IOException  if there was a problem scanning for or loading a TLD
 * @throws SAXException if there was a problem parsing a TLD
 */
protected void scanResourcePaths(String startPath)
        throws IOException, SAXException {

    boolean found = false;
    Set<String> dirList = context.getResourcePaths(startPath);
    if (dirList != null) {
        for (String path : dirList) {
            if (path.startsWith("/WEB-INF/classes/")) {
                // Skip: JSP.7.3.1
            } else if (path.startsWith("/WEB-INF/lib/")) {
                // Skip: JSP.7.3.1
            } else if (path.endsWith("/")) {
                scanResourcePaths(path);
            } else if (path.startsWith("/WEB-INF/tags/")) {
                // JSP 7.3.1: in /WEB-INF/tags only consider implicit.tld
                if (path.endsWith("/implicit.tld")) {
                    found = true;
                    parseTld(path);
                }
            } else if (path.endsWith(TLD_EXT)) {
                found = true;
                parseTld(path);
            }
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug(Localizer.getMessage("jsp.tldCache.tldInResourcePath", startPath));
        }
    } else {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug(Localizer.getMessage("jsp.tldCache.noTldInResourcePath", startPath));
        }
    }
}
```

and

`jsp.tldCache.noTldInResourcePath=No TLD files were found in resource path [{0}].`